# how to upload list of documents in java

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, httprequest, resttemplate

I want to upload a list of object from client to the server via rest template in spring framework.

i have a list of PDDocument and BufferedImage objects and i want them to upload on the server

here is my code

```
private void uploadDocs(List<Prescription> prescriptions, BufferedImage stampImage) {
   List<Object> pDDocumentList = new ArryaList<>();
   List<Object> imageList = new ArryaList<>();
   Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
   for (Prescription prescription : prescriptions) {
      PDDocument pdfDoc = MyUtility.insertImageTopdf(doc, stampImage, noOfPrescription);
      pDDocumentList.add(pdfDoc);
      BufferedImage updatedImage = Utility.createImage(pdfDoc, 0);
      imageList.add(updatedImage);
   }
  map.put("Image", imageList);
  map.put("Pdf", pDDocumentList);
}
```

now i want to post this map from here to another service via rest template, 
and it shows following exception, please help

```
    org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->in.lifcare.core.model.DocumentRequestObject["document"]->org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument["document"]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument["trailer"]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary["values"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues[0]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSObject["object"]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary["values"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues[0]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName["cosobject"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->in.lifcare.core.model.DocumentRequestObject["document"]->org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument["document"]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument["trailer"]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary["values"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues[0]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSObject["object"]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary["values"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues[0]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName["cosobject"])
      at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:292)
      at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:863)
      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:650)
      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
      at in.lifcare.core.util.MicroserviceClient.patchForObject(MicroserviceClient.java:161)
      at in.lifcare.ops.facility.microservices.account.service.impl.AccountServiceImpl.replaceDocs(AccountServiceImpl.java:74)
      at in.lifcare.ops.prescription.service.impl.StampServiceImpl.replaceDocs(StampServiceImpl.java:216)
      at in.lifcare.ops.prescription.service.impl.StampServiceImpl.save(StampServiceImpl.java:134)
      at in.lifcare.ops.prescription.api.PrescriptionController.save1(PrescriptionController.java:47)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
      at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
      at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->in.lifcare.core.model.DocumentRequestObject["document"]->org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument["document"]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument["trailer"]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary["values"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues[0]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSObject["object"]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary["values"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues[0]->org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName["cosobject"])
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:284)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.mappingException(SerializerProvider.java:1110)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportMappingProblem(SerializerProvider.java:1135)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._handleSelfReference(BeanPropertyWriter.java:921)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:698)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:112)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:112)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:416)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1425)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:951)
      at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:285)
      ... 82 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With very minimal available code and as per the exception, it seems you have cyclic references in your objects, which you are trying to serialize. Please check your model if you are having cyclic reference.

Try to `@JsonIdentityInfo` on your model which you are trying to deseralize to resolve the same.

For more details on its usage please check [JsonIdentityInfo](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html)